# Reason for HERE api 504 response?

Tags: here-api

We've been using the HERE Fleet Telematics API for well over a year now, but this past week have had several instances of 504 response codes. Our primary question is, is HERE down, and if so, how can we check this? HERE seems to have no status page and only provides email support. For all inquiries, they suggest to post here on stack overflow.

The error we're getting is

```
Gateway Timeout { results: null,
  errors: 
    [ 'Technical error while generating the response. Please contact TCS.\r\nError ID: d4f2ecc9-9f23-4167-940b-a0d179370902' ], 
  processingTimeDesc: null, 
  responseCode: '504', 
  warnings: null, 
  requestId: null
}
```

Has anyone else run into this? Were you able to get in contact with the HERE team to confirm that this is an error on their side?

Comment: This sort of sounds like you're asking for technical support with their service.  Did you try emailing selfservesupport@here.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status API/page for HERE Location Services are planned and will be released in the near future. For now please use StackOverflow and the support email (if you have a paid plan). If you are still getting the 504 error, please let us know.